# Оптимизация кода Python. Создание GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

Небольшая работа по программированию в вузе. Есть предложения по оптимизации кода? Было бы интересно.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from graph import *

def check(file):                # Проверка на наличие записей в файле
        file = open(FILE)
        if file.read() != '':
                file.close()
                return True
        else:
                file.close()
                return None

def name_input():        #Функция ввода названия и обработки того же файла
        global MASSIVE, kind_of_sport, SECOND_NAME, STROKA, FILE, CHOICE, choice
        SECOND_NAME = []
        kind_of_sport = []
        MASSIVE = []
        info = [0, 0]
        STROKA = 3

        if file_name.get() != '':               # Проверка на отсутствие ввода
                FILE = file_name.get() + '.txt' # Получение введённой информации без указания формата
                file_name.delete(0, END)                                  
                try:                            # Обработка случая, когда файла с таким именем не существет
                    F = open(FILE)
                    if check(F) == True:
                            f = open(FILE)               
                            text2.grid(column = 0, row = 1) # 'Выберите вид спорта, по которому хотите вывести информация' 
                            for row in f:
                                row = row[:-1]
                                row = row.split(';') 
                                if row[2] not in kind_of_sport:
                                        kind_of_sport.append(row[2])    # Список с видами спорта
                                SECOND_NAME.append(row[0])
                                info[0] = row.pop(2)
                                info[1] = list(row)
                                MASSIVE.append(list(info))

                            CHOICE_BUTTON = InputButton('Искать по дисциплине:')        # Кнопка 'Искать по дисциплине'
                            choice = Entry(root, width=28)                              # Поле ввода для дисциплины
                            choice.grid(column = 1, row = 3)                            # Размещение поля для ввода дисциплины

                            sprt = 'Виды спорта:\n'
                            for kind in kind_of_sport:                                  # Создание предложения 'Виды спорта:...'
                                    sprt = sprt + kind + ',\n'         
                            text5 = Label(root, text = sprt[:-2] + '.',bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white', width = 26) # Метка 'Виды спорта......'
                            text5.grid(column = 1, row = 1)             

                    else:                       
                         messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка', 'Файл пуст')       
                except FileNotFoundError:       # Обработка случая, когда файла с таким именем не существет
                    messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка ввода', 'Файла с таким именем не существует') # Всплывающее окно в случае, когда файла с таким именем не существет
                SECOND_NAME.sort()
                QUIT_button.grid(column = 0, row = STROKA + 2)
        else:
                QUIT_button.grid(column = 0, row = STROKA + 2)
                messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка ввода', 'Вы ничего не ввели')   # Всплывающее окно в случае, когда поле ввода пустое

class InputButton:      # Конпка 'Искать по дисциплине'
        def __init__(self, name):
                self.button_name = name
                self.b = Button(root, text = self.button_name, width = 20, bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white', command = self.click) # Создание и разиещение кнопки
                self.b.grid(column = 0, row = 3)

        def click(self):        # Действие кнопки при нажатии
                vid_sporta = choice.get()
                choice.delete(0, END)
                graph_name_COLOUR = '#3f4b59'
                if vid_sporta in kind_of_sport:

                        COVER = Label(root, width = 80, height = 50, bg = '#3f4b59')     #Жёлтый фон
                        COVER.place(x = 358, y = 51)

                        brushColor('white')             # Белый холст для окна с графиком
                        rectangle(0, 0, scale, scale)
                        penSize(2)                      

                        points = []             
                        sportsmen_AGE = []
                        sportsmen_NAME = {}
                        VOZRAST = {}

                        col = 2         # Начальная колонка
                        ROW = 1

                        name_of_sport = Label(root, text = 'Вид спорта', bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')        # Названия полей
                        second_name = Label(root, text = 'Фамилия', width = 15, bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white') # Фамилия
                        age = Label(root, text = 'Возраст', bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')                     # Возраст
                        placement = Label(root, text = 'Место', bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')                 # Занятое место
                        text3.grid(column = 4, row = 0)                 # Метка 'Самый молодой спортсмен, занимающийся данным видом спорта'


                        youngest_sportsmen.grid(column = 5, row = 0)    # Фамилия самого молодого спортсмена
                        name_of_sport.grid(column = col, row = ROW)     # Размещение полей
                        second_name.grid(column = col + 1, row = ROW)   # Фамилия
                        age.grid(column = col + 2, row = ROW)           # Возраст
                        placement.grid(column = col + 3, row = ROW)     # Занятое место

                        nazvanieSPORTA = Label(root, text = vid_sporta, width = 14, bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')       # Название вида спорта
                        nazvanieSPORTA.grid(column = col, row = ROW + 1)                        # Размещение названия вида спорта

                        for name in SECOND_NAME:                                        # Перебор отсортированного списка
                                for sportsmen_info in MASSIVE:                          # Размещение информации о спортсменах
                                        if name in sportsmen_info[1]:                   # "Сортировка"
                                                if sportsmen_info[0] == vid_sporta:     # "Если вид спорта совпадает с названием кнопки" 


                                                        sportsmen_AGE.append(sportsmen_info[1][1])                      # Список с фамилиями для сортировки
                                                        sportsmen_NAME[sportsmen_info[1][1]] = sportsmen_info[1][0]     # Словарь с возрастом спортсмена

                                                        ROW += 1                                                        # Строка для размещения кнопки

                                                        NAME = Label(root, text = sportsmen_info[1][0], width = 15, bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')     # Фамилия
                                                        NAME.grid(column = col + 1, row = ROW)                                                                # Размещение

                                                        AGE = Label(root, text = sportsmen_info[1][1], width = 15, bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')      # Возраст
                                                        AGE.grid(column = col + 2, row = ROW)                                                                 # Размещение

                                                        PLACEMENT = Label(root, text = sportsmen_info[1][2], width = 10, bg = graph_name_COLOUR, fg = 'white')# Место
                                                        PLACEMENT.grid(column = col + 3, row = ROW)                                                           # Размещение
                        y = 360
                        line(20, y, y*2, y) # X
                        line(20, 0, 20, y)  # Y

                        for x in range(50, 350, 50):
                                line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5)    # Штрихи по X
                                line(15, x+10, 25, x+10)    # Штрихи по Y

                        y0 = 310 # Нижний штрих по Y
                        x0 = 50  # Левый штрих по X

                        youngest_sportsmen.configure(text = sportsmen_NAME[str(sportsmen_AGE[0])], bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white', width = 14, height = 2)    # Вывод фамилии самого молодого спортсмена

                        for i in range(int(min(sportsmen_AGE)), int(max(sportsmen_AGE)) + 1):
                                VOZRAST[i] = y  # Заполнение словаря с возрастом и его координатой
                                y -= 50

                        for n in sportsmen_AGE:
                                points.append((x0, VOZRAST[int(n)])) # Заполнение списка с координатами точек
                                x0 += 50

                        try:                    # Обработка случая, когда есть лишь одна точка
                                polyline(points)
                        except:                 # Отображение той самой точки
                                penSize(5)      
                                point(x0, y0)   # Ставится лишь одна точка
                elif vid_sporta == '':
                        messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка ввода', 'Ничего не было введено')   # Всплывающее окно в случае, если ничего не было введено
                else:
                        messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка ввода', 'Такого вида спорта нет')   # Всплывающее окно в случае, если такого вида спорта нет
                QUIT_button.grid(column = 0, row = 5)

def Quit():     # Функция для кнопки выхода из программы
        root.destroy()
        close()

def start():
        global file_name, text2, root, QUIT_button, scale, text3, youngest_sportsmen
        START.destroy()
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Сухомлин, 18-ИЭ-2')
        scale = 400                     # 
        canvasSize(scale, scale)        #
        windowSize(scale, scale)        # Настройки графика
        penSize(2)                      #
        penColor('black')               #

        MAINCOVER = Label(root, bg = 'black', width = 300, height = 300) # Основной фон
        MAINCOVER.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        file_name = Entry(root, width=30)       #Поле ввода
        text1 = Label(root, text = 'Введите название файла', bg = 'black', fg = 'white', height = 3)
        text2 = Label(root, text = 'Выберите вид спорта,\n информацию по которому\n хотите вывести информацию',bg = '#3f4b59', fg ='white', height = 6)
        text3 = Label(root, text = 'Самый молодой спортсмен,\n занимающийся данным видом спорта:', bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white')
        text4 = Label(root, text = 'Сухомлин Георгий\n 18-ИЭ-2', bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
        youngest_sportsmen = Label(root)
        QUIT_button = Button(root, text = 'Выйти', command = Quit, bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white') # Кнопка завершения работы
        Input_button = Button(root, text = 'Открыть', command = name_input, width = 15, bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white')  #Кнопка ввода

        text1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)         #   "Введите название файла"
        text4.grid(column = 3, row = 0)
        file_name.grid(column = 1, row = 0)     #   Поле ввода
        Input_button.grid(column = 2, row = 0)  #   Кнопка ввода
        QUIT_button.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

        file_name.focus() # Начальная фокусировка на поле ввода
        run()
        root.mainloop()


START = Tk()
START.title('Добро пожаловать')
START.geometry('300x100+850+400')
cover = Label(START, bg = 'black',height = 100, width = 100)
cover.place(x = 0, y = 0)
start_button = Button(START, text = 'Начать работу', command = start, width = 30, height = 5, bg = '#3f4b59', fg = 'white')
start_button.place(x = 40, y = 7)
START.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не использовать глобальные переменные)

Comment: И переписать в ООП стиле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мои замечания по коду:

---

- `from tkinter import *`

  Не надо так делать:

  - возможны коллизии и затенение имен переменных;
  - неэффективно при большом количестве импортируемых имён;
  - сложно разобраться, откуда берется та или иная переменная в коде

  На мой взгляд, лучше всегда использовать: `import module` или `import module as m` и затем обращаться к именам модуля через `.`: `module.test` или `m.test`

---

- `if file_name.get() != '':`

  Как правило, заменяется на `if file_name.get():`. Изучите, в том числе [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), какие значения переменных приравниваются в Python к `False`. В их числе, например, `''`, `[]`, `{}`

---

- Множественные ступеньки в цикле:

  ```
  for sportsmen_info in MASSIVE:
      if name in sportsmen_info[1]:
          if sportsmen_info[0] == vid_sporta: 
              sportsmen_AGE.append(sportsmen_info[1][1])
  ```

  Можно заменять таким кодом:

  ```
  for sportsmen_info in MASSIVE:
      if not name in sportsmen_info[1]: continue
      if not sportsmen_info[0] == vid_sporta: continue
      sportsmen_AGE.append(sportsmen_info[1][1])
  ```

  В функциях аналогичным методом можно обрабатывать более короткие варианты кода сначала и делать return, тем самым убирая одну ступеньку, например:

  ```
  if not file_name.get():
      QUIT_button.grid(column = 0, row = STROKA + 2)
      messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка ввода', 'Вы ничего не ввели')
      return

  FILE = file_name.get() + '.txt'
  ...
  ```

---

- `def check(file):`

  Можно переписать покороче (а если вникнуть, то и ещё короче, но я оставлю if как у Вас). Кстати, зачем здесь у функции параметр, Вы его всё равно не используете:

  ```
  def check():
      with open(FILE) as file:
          return file.read() != ''
  ```

  Используя `with`, не нужно заботится о закрытии файла, это произойдёт автоматически при выходе из блока `with`

  Раз Вы возвращаете `True`, то логично возвращать вторым вариантом `False`, а не `None`

---

- Делайте отступы в 4 символа, как рекомендовано в [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) - 8 слишком много

---

### Добавлено

- `def check(file):`

  Я всегда стараюсь править чужой код по минимуму. Но в данном случае, как правильно сказали в комментариях, использование глобальной переменной уж очень не очень.

  Так что параметр мы как раз оставим, а вот вызов функции придется переписать тоже:

  ```
  def check(file):
      with open(file) as f:
          return f.read() != ''


  # F = open(FILE) - это - выкидывается совсем
  if check(FILE): # здесь выкинули == True
  ```
- `FILE`:

  Переменные в Python принято именовать как слова из строчных букв с подчёркиваниями. Все прописные буквы обычно используют для имён констант. Снова [ссылка на PEP 8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id17)

Comment: По поводу `continue` и ступенек не согласен: никак не повышает читаемость, и очень легко неправильно построить отрицание условия (особенно если не знать законы де Моргана). По поводу `check(file)` - я бы наоборот посоветовал избавиться от глобальных переменных, а передавать все через параметры.

Comment: @insolor Насчёт глобальных переменных - правильно сказано. Добавил в ответ. Насчёт ступенек и отрицания условия - ничего, полезно головой поработать - реверсировать логику. Всё равно, тесты никто не отменял...